# Vanilla JavaScript AJAX form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I need help to make a form submit using AJAX in Vanilla JavaScript (No jQuery).
I have this jQuery Code that i need converted to JavaScript.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myForm').submit(function (event) {
      var data = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        type: data.attr('method'),
        url: data.attr('action'),
        data: data.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {

        }
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_examples.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-can-i-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the built-in [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for AJAX calls and [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to parse your form.

Other than that, just replace your jquery with event listeners, query selectors, and attribute getters.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('.myForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    var data = this;
    fetch(data.getAttribute('action'), {
      method: data.getAttribute('method'),
      body: new FormData(data)
    }).then(res=>res.text())
      .then(function (data) {
        
      });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try. But it seems like you missed 2 parentheses?

Comment: @TimLevinsson yes, fixed

Comment: I have tried it. I am trying to get the data from the php file as i can do with the jQuery. I tried like this
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('.myForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      var data = this
      fetch(data.getAttribute('action'), {
        method: data.getAttribute('method'),
        body: new FormData(data)
      }).then(res=>res.text())

      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
      })
      event.preventDefault()
    })
  })

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to wrap in code in the comments...

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that when i do console.log(data) it does not return the content from the php file. It returns all the html code from the html file

Comment: nvm... All works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
// Document loaded event listener
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Get al forms with a specific CSS class
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.ajax-form');
    if (forms && forms.length) {
        forms.forEach(form => {

            form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {

                // Prevent form submission
                evt.preventDefault();           
                
                // Fetch data from {url}
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.withCredentials = false;
            
                xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
                    if (this.readyState === 4) {
    
                        // Fetch and process data
                        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
    
                // Get form data
                var data = new FormData(form),
                    method = form.getAttribute('method'),
                    url = form.getAttribute('action');
    
                // Debug
                console.log({
                    data: data,
                    method: method,
                    url: url
                });
            
                // Send a GET/POST/PUT/DELTE request
                xhr.open(method, url);
                xhr.send(data);
            })
        });
    }
});
```